# .htaccess RewriteCond

Tags: php, .htaccess

Это пропускает на .mkv файл с пустым referer и site.com referer. С остальных доменов блокирует. Как сделать так, чтобы бликировало при наличии .mkv в конце referer, а остальное так же пропускало?

Comment: дак и добавьте еще один `RewriteCond` c проверкой `\.mkv$`

Comment: Добавлял, не работает. Если в referer в конце присутствует .mkv, всё-равно пропускает.

Comment: Возможно что-то не так делаю, приведите пожалуйста готовый код с тем, что выше.

Comment: И можно ли указать в строку строку как-то?